# Celery v4 group task behaviour with redis backend

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

So I had been using celery v3.x for a bit of a time now and thought about migrating to v4 since its out officially.  Right now, I'm using the v4.0.2 that's available through PyPI. There were few mismatches in both the versions, but the one which confuses me is this:

Here is my tasks file:

```
from celery import group, chord
from worker import app


@app.task(name='task')
def task(i):
    return i


@app.task(name='remaining')
def dummy(result):
    print result

@app.task(name='mainTask')
def mainTask():
    groupTask = group([task.s(i) for i in range(0,10)])
    job = chord(groupTask, dummy.s())()
    return job
```

When I call the `mainTask`, the subsequent group task do get executed, but when I try to print the results of this task through `dummy`, the order of result is getting messed up. A sample output would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 9, 7, 5]
```

The weird thing is, this happens only if the result backend is redis. On using amqp, the results appear in exact order like:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

P.S., This behaviour was NOT present in the older version of celery. Redis as well as amqp returned the results in the correct order. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer for anyone else who might be facing the same issue.

The redis backend code in celery is written in such a way that the results get pushed to a redis list, as soon as it finishes, and hence the change in order.

I had posted the same query in celery's github issues page and got the [answer](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3781#issuecomment-279135257) from one of the contributors.